# Can every constant be written in that way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, exponential-sum

When we are working in the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ where the elements are of the form $$\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i e^{\lambda_i x}$$ where $\alpha_i, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$, can every constant be written in the form $e^b$, for some $b$?

Comment: sure, $c=e^{\ln c}$

Comment: I don't understand your introduction to what seems to be the question. If you ask if any complex number $c$ can be written as $e^b$ for some complex $b$, then yeah, except for $c=0$.

Comment: I see... Thank you both!! :-)